# "I've watched a video..." or "I've watched the video..."

Tags: grammar, articles

I want to tell to my friends that I've watched some video and give them *the* link.
How I should write this message in instant messanger or in twitter?

> I've watched *a* wonderful video about ... You can watch it here

or

> I've watched *the* wonderful video about ... You can watch it here

Comment: A good rule of thumb is you use *the* if you expect your readers to know what video you're talking about (even if it's only because you just defined it), *a* if you don't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The** video implies that this is a specific video, whereas **a** video implies that it is only one of multiple videos.

For example, you watch **a** video about Calculus, but you would watch **the** video that was assigned for your math class.

With your example, it could go either way.

- I watched **a** wonderful video that explains Quantum Physics. Here is the link.

This works because there are many videos that try to explain Quantum Physics. So you use **a**.

- Here is a link to the wonderful video we talked about earlier.

You would use **the** here, because we are referring to a specific video.

In other words, you use **the** when there is no ambiguity. If you say **the** video, no one would question which video you are referring to (at least that's what the speaker is implying). **A** video is ambiguous and doesn't refer to a specific video, that is what your link is for.

Comment: This explains well why 'the' is called the 'definite article' and why 'a' is called the 'indefinite article'.

Comment: @toandfro Good point! I never really put that together for some reason.